# Can a Cisco ASA firewall do force remote VPN?

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn

Right now I have Remote Access VPN configured to use fulltunnel. Right now when I am off the VPN I can still browse external sites (google, yahoo, etc) which is using my local ISP. If I want to VPN into my network, I need to open up Cisco Anyconnect desktop client and enter the vpn URL and my credentials. Once I am connected all my traffic is going through my companies ISP circuit/ASA firewall.

Is there a way to force VPN on a Cisco ASA firewall so a user can not use their computer unless they are VPN into company network? Meaning as soon as they log on they can not browse the internet or get to email until they VPN into network.

Meaning, is there a setting in ASA that tells it to connect to VPN automatically when there is an internet connection?

Any information would be most helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Meaning,  is there a setting in ASA  that tells it to connect to VPN automatically when there is an internet connection?

Comment: Have a look at the "always on" feature : https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect40/administration/guide/b_AnyConnect_Administrator_Guide_4-0/configure-vpn.html#topic_BD02A53E0A714E23A56850698C830A6C

Comment: @hertitu, that doesn't control the computer when it is not connected to the ASA, and that is the question. The question asks how to prevent the computer from accessing the Internet when _not_ connected, but then the PC could not connect to the ASA in the first place.

Comment: @RonMaupin it does control the computer when it is not connected, it only allows a connection to the ASA and nothing else.

Comment: The ASA will even edit the any connect software by editing the ASA. The host computer doesn't need direct editing at all. No GPOs. It's automatic when they connect. Then after that the Cisco software does the job. It's pretty slick. You can have it start when the host logs into the computer automatically as well. No editing the host. All done from the ASA.

Comment: If the user has rights to manipulate firewall settings I agree with Ron. Otherwise it's pretty slick. You can remote in if the user has been logged off for a while because it'll disconnect but most users PCs sleep anyway. I think there's issues with proxies too.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can.

The Anyconnect VPN client has a feature named "Always On":

> Always-On operation prevents access to Internet resources when the
>   computer is not on a trusted network, unless a VPN session is active.
>   Enforcing the VPN to always be on in this situation protects the
>   computer from security threats.

Cisco documentation: [Require VPN Connections Using Always-On](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect40/administration/guide/b_AnyConnect_Administrator_Guide_4-0/configure-vpn.html#topic_BD02A53E0A714E23A56850698C830A6C)

Note that this feature is configured in the Anyconnect client profile, which can either be pre-deployed or pushed from the ASA. Obviously, if you want the feature to be active from day zero, even before the user makes his first VPN connection, then you need to pre-deploy the profile.

Also note that the comments mentioned concerns about the user being able to circumvent this feature by defining their home (or coffee shop) network as "trusted" in the Windows firewall settings. Anyconnect does *not* use the Windows firewall settings for trusted networks. Instead it uses another Anyconnect feature named *Trusted Network Detection* (TND) feature which allows the ASA admin to control which networks are considered trusted based on the DNS settings of the client.

cfr. [Configure Trusted Network Detection](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect40/administration/guide/b_AnyConnect_Administrator_Guide_4-0/configure-vpn.html#ID-1428-00000178)

Comment: Even if host configuration is off-topic here, it is worth noting that it's quite easy to undermine with administrative privilege on the machine, and it's also quite easy to gain administrative privilege on most operating systems. This kind of policy need a well-hardened O.S. to be effective.

Comment: I think if a user goes through that trouble it's time to have a serious discussion! Thanks for the info on the trusted domain hertitu. Great info